# Searching through nested list

Tags: python, list, nltk, text-analysis

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

list_1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
list_2 = [[aa, bb, cc], [dd, ee], [ff], [gg, hh, ii, jj], [kk, ll], [mm, nn, oo]]
text = 'The lazy aa moves along the hh'
text_token = word_tokenize(text)

for word in text:
     if word in [j for i in list_2 for j in i]:
        print(list_2.index(word))
     else:
        print(word)

ValueError: 'hh' is not in list
```

I'm attempting textual analysis on large bodies of French text. I have already tried using the NLTK Stemmer and it doesn't stem a significant amount of words that I'm analyzing.

I'm not very familiar with python or any of the other coding languages (I'm coming from the Humanities) so I'm also not entirely sure as to how to search for the issue that I'm looking for, and I apologize in  if this question is either redundant or easily solved.

I've attempted to approach this by finding a list of French words with their various grammatical forms. I already complied the list into two separate lists: the first list contains the root of the word that I would like the others to take on, while the second list is the variant forms that the item in the first list can take on. I've made it so that both lists correspond to each other. For example, `list_1[0]` would correspond to the words in `list_2[0]`. As a result, there are a lot of nested lists of different lengths within list_2.

My issue seems to arise when I'm searching through nested lists. I have to iterate through `text_token` to check if any of the words in `text_token` exist in `list_2`. If `text_token` exists in `list_2` then find `misc = list_2.index(word)` . After finding `misc`, I want to replace word with search `list_1[misc]`. However, after confirming that word exists in `list_2`, I try to `print(list_2.index(word))` to see if it works, but i keep receiving `ValueError: 'hh' is not in list` I'm not entirely sure how to cycle through nested lists after already having done so in order to avoid this error, because I'm assuming that when I search through the definitions a second time, it doesn't see the nested list as multiple items. I've tried to circumvent this by trying another list comprehension after checking it in the original one, but it ends up returning individual letters. I've also tried making these two lists into a dictionary, but I can't seem to figure out how to yield `.keys()` from `.values()`.

Comment: You really don't want to be using nested lists like this! Use a `dict`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really just want a map, i.e. a `dict`. You can quickly munge your current data into a map using the following dict comprehension*:

```
rootmap = {var:root for root, variants in zip(list1, list2) for var in variants}
```

Then you can use:

```
print(rootmap.get(word, word))
```

This uses the `.get` method, which takes a second value as a default in case the first argument isn't found. As an aside, `dict` membership testing is much more efficient than checking a list, it is a constant time operation, whereas for a list membership tests are linear operations. This becomes more important if you are using this many times with many varients in `list2`.

*The equivalent can also be written using for-loops:

```
rootmap = {}
for root, variants in zip(list1, list2): # iterate over your lists in parallel
    for var in variants:
        rootmap[var] = root
```

**Caveat**:

Read more about `dict`s in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Keep in mind, `dict`s map *unique keys* to values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain the index of the sublist in the main list, you can do:

```
for word in text:
     for index, sublist in enumerate(list_2):
         if word in sublist:
             print(index)
             break
     else:
        print(word)
```

`enumerate(list_2)` iterates on the elements of list_2, which are your sublists, and yields at each step the index of the sublist and the sublist itself.

Then, we check if the word is in one of the sublists.

- If this is the case, we print the index and `break` out of the inner `for` loop.
- If we didn't find the word in any of the sublists, we execute the `else` part of the `for` loop and print the word.